# Add css class to menu item based on current url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have menu and I want to add css class to menu item based on current url

I try to use jQuery but this code add current-active-menu css class only to `a href="https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/` element

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/") > -1) {
    $('a[href="https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/"]').addClass("current-active-menu");
  }
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/?candidate-page=resumes-list") > -1) {
    $('a[href="https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/?candidate-page=resumes-list"]').addClass("current-active-menu");
  }
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/?candidate-page=my-orders") > -1) {
    $('a[href="https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/?candidate-page=my-orders"]').addClass("current-active-menu");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `else if` and put `https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/` at the end because it would match your other 2:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/?candidate-page=my-orders") > -1) {
    $('a[href="https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/?candidate-page=my-orders"]').addClass("current-active-menu");
  } else if (window.location.href.indexOf("https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/?candidate-page=resumes-list") > -1) {
    $('a[href="https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/?candidate-page=resumes-list"]').addClass("current-active-menu");
  } else if (window.location.href.indexOf("https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/") > -1) {
    $('a[href="https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/"]').addClass("current-active-menu");
  }
});
```

Also it looks like you whole url should match so you should think about using `===` in your if instead of `indexOf`:

`window.location.href === "https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/?candidate-page=my-orders"`

With your original problem, using `indexOf` put the active class onto the wrong link because you were testing if that string exists anywhere in the url (which `https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/` exists in all three of your urls you test)